# SQL - Is it possible to check if row value is 'public' only if row type is 'privacy'?

Tags: sql

I have two tabels. One with Products and the other with product meta data.

My SQL string: `` SELECT * FROM `Products` LEFT JOIN `ProductsMeta` ON `ProductsMeta`.`product_id` = `Products`.`product_id` WHERE `ProductsMeta`.`meta_value` = 'public' OR `ProductsMeta`.`meta_value` IS NULL ``

But the problem is not every product needs a privacy meta row, and therefor im checking if its NULL, but if a product has anything else in the product meta, unrelated to the privacy setting, it's not shown in the select query.

Therefor i tried: `` SELECT * FROM `Products` LEFT JOIN `ProductsMeta` ON `ProductsMeta`.`product_id` = `Products`.`product_id` WHERE (`ProductsMeta`.`meta_value` = 'public' OR `ProductsMeta`.`meta_value` IS NULL) AND `ProductsMeta`.`meta_type` = '_privacy' ``

But that returns 0 results. Because only one product has a meta entry with _privacy, and that is set to unlisted.

Is it possible to ONLY check `` `ProductsMeta`.`meta_value` = 'public' OR `ProductsMeta`.`meta_value` IS NULL `` IF `` `ProductsMeta`.`meta_type` = '_privacy' `` And not anything else like keyword, or filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the filtering condition to the `ON` clause.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     ProductsMeta pm
     ON pm.product_id = p.product_id AND
        pm.meta_value = 'public' AND
        pm.meta_type = '_privacy';
```